# Static route captured by parametrized one

Tags: angular, routes

Is it possible to set up Angular routes so that parameter is not confused with another route?

Say, routes as follows:

```
{
  path: 'heroes/:id',
  component: HeroDetailComponent
},
{
  path: 'heroes/add',
  component: HeroEditComponent
},
```

will conflict, in that the segment `add` will be captured and interpreted as `:id` or distinguish those routes in another way.

Is it possible to hook up a regexp to determine correct route?

Comment: Have You tried reverting the order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular Router will take the first route that matches so you should define your routes from most specific to least specific. If you switch the order then `add` should be matched first and then `:id`.

```js
{
  path: 'heroes/add',
  component: HeroEditComponent
},
{
  path: 'heroes/:id',
  component: HeroDetailComponent
},
```